# Glew's glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1") returning false on MBP OSX 10.10.1 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M

Tags: macos, opengl, glew, xserver

I am trying to run a program which requires OpenGL 3.1 on my Macbook Pro Retina from mid 2012 running OSX 10.10.1 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M. I installed Glew through Homebrew and running `glewinfo` shows the following:

```
GL_VERSION_3_1:                                              OK 
---------------
glDrawArraysInstanced:                                       OK
glDrawElementsInstanced:                                     OK
glPrimitiveRestartIndex:                                     OK
glTexBuffer:                                                 OK
```

However, when the line `glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1")` in the code I'm running returns false. I searched online and found something about X Server on OSX supporting only up to OpenGL 2.1 and thought that this could be the problem.

So I also downloaded [GLView](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) and noticed that when I switch from Core to Compatibility the OpenGL version goes down from 4.1 to 2.1. I suppose this means that `glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1")` checks for the compatibility version and not the core. If I change that check to `GL_VERSION_2_1` are there any risks for my graphics card or my computer in general? Is there a way to know if the code requires core or compatibility? And if it does require X Server, is there a way to get X Server to use OpenGL 3.1?

[EDIT: These are the headers.]

```
...
#include <GL/glew.h>

#ifdef __linux__
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you are even using the X server in this example. XQuartz does limit you to OpenGL 2.1, but if you are using something like GLFW that actually sits on top of the platform native window system (it uses NSOpenGL instead of GLX).

Comment: Why are you using GLEW on a Mac? You don't need extension loading on OSX, which is the main reason for using GLEW on other platforms.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, I don't know if the code requires X Server. I was hoping there was a way to check if it required it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, when I ran `cmake` it said it required it and I see it in the headers, which I have added to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens on more than just OS X, it's because GLEW has poor support for Open GL core contexts.  For example, this also happens on my Linux system with Mesa: it reports version 3.0, even though 3.3 is actually supported.

On OS X, I recommend the following:

- You must create a core context in order to get an OpenGL version other than 2.1.  If you do not request a core context, you will always get 2.1.  (The `glewinfo` program fails to request a core context, so it always reports version 2.1 on OS X.)
- Use `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>` and just call the functions directly.  The functions in this header will be NULL if they are not available on your system... just as if you had used GLEW.
- Check the version number and the presence of extensions normally, using `glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION)`, `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION)` and `glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS)`.

GLEW is utterly worthless on OS X.  The library is supposed to do three things:

1. It loads function pointers.  This is unnecessary on OS X, because OS X lets you access those functions just by linking against the OpenGL framework, and because those functions are weakly linked, your application will still run even if they are unavailable.  This kind of weak linking is not available on Linux or Windows.
2. It detects the presence of Open GL extensions.  However, GLEW completely and utterly fails to do this in core contexts because it calls `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` instead of `glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, n)`.  Whoops!  GLEW detects extensions incorrectly on *all* platforms.
3. It detects the presence of Open GL versions.  You can do this yourself with `glGetIntegerv(GL_VERSION_MAJOR)` and `glGetIntegerv(GL_VERSION_MINOR)`.

This is why I don't recommend GLEW on OS X.  At least on Windows and Linux, it is useful because it loads function pointers.

### Checking the version

> I suppose this means that `glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_1")` checks for the compatibility version and not the core. If I change that check to `GL_VERSION_2_1` are there any risks for my graphics card or my computer in general?

GLEW doesn't know anything about core or compatibility.  It just asks for the version of the context that you give it.  The reason that it's reporting version 2.1 is because that is the *actual, true version* of the context you are using.  The *actual version* of Open GL is different on OS X depending on whether you use the core or compatibility context.

(Note that on some platforms and drivers, you will also get different versions depending on which version you ask for, but this does not apply to OS X.)

### What version of Open GL does this code require?

> Is there a way to know if the code requires core or compatibility?

That's an annoying and tedious task, unfortunately.  There is no easy way to figure out what version of Open GL your code requires.  You can download the relevant Open GL specification and read your code, but here is something to start with:

- Look at the GLSL versions.  Each GLSL version corresponds to a version of Open GL.  1.20 = OpenGL 2.1, for example.  Note that core contexts are not required to support GLSL versions *lower* than 1.40.
- If your code uses VAOs (vertex array objects), then assume OpenGL 3.x or higher.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This really sheds light on how these tools work. I'm going through the code now and trying to see if I can get it to work with your recommendations.